# XCode / Interface Builder : How to rename the default NSToolbar Items?

Tags: xcode, nstoolbar

When I add an NSToolbar to my application it comes with some default items like "Customize" or "Colors" and I am unable to rename them. These attributes are disabled and can not be edited.

I am looking for an easy way to translate these items since I don't need an English application. I also would like to edit the text of the "done" Button and the text "Allowed toolbar items".

I am really looking for an easy way to do this since I am working on a tutorial for kids and I would not like to do an overall localization if I don't have to. Anyway, I would do if it's not to complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's default toolbar items are already localized for many countries. To use another language in your application, you have localize your app by adding an appropriate 'Countryname.lproj' directory to your 'Resources' dir in your app wrapper.

By default XCode creates the 'English.lproj' localization only. If you don't need english you can just rename it to 'German.lproj' (or whatever). You have to add the contained files to your project again and remove the old references.

You also might want to set the 'Localization native development region' setting in your Info.plist file to your country.

I do not know of a way to let InterfaceBuilder show another localization, it always uses English.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a bounty well spend. I really needed to know this.